# Correct way of converting DateTime string in timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

Which is correct way of converting datetime string in format like '2014-12-06 07:45' in timestamp ?
I make like

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i", '2014-12-06 07:45' );
```

but time is zero...

Comment: please search this site repository before posting this kind of repeatative questions.

Comment: You get zero cause the second argument should be timestamp (integer), not a string.  Please, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and try to view every relevant function on the right part of that page.

Answer (score 1):

Flexible format way:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2014-12-06 07:45');

echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
echo strtotime("2014-12-06 07:45");
```

Output:

```
1417848300
```